# How can I take an output path of "which somemodule" as an argument of "ls"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

As you know, call "which anymodule" returns its path to the command like this:

```
which git
```

This command above returns the path like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

**So how can I take this output as an argument of another command**, e.g. ls?
So it looks like this:

```
ls (which git)
```

which when calling, I want it to be parsed into:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/git
```

So I don't need to manually copy the output and paste it as an argument of another command which I know this is silly.

**So far, I have tried this:**

```
ls | which git
```

Above doesn't work, it doesn't take the output of "which git" as an argument of "ls". So then I tried:

```
ls `which git`
```

Above either doesn't work. "which git" doesn't actually get parsed into an argument of "ls". I have explored through various articles but I can't find an answer to this.

Can anybody please suggest me a proper solution?

Comment: Why you want to pass `/usr/local/bin/git` as an argument of `ls` ?

Comment: `ls \`which git\`` should work fine (and does on my machine) (unless `git` is in a path with spaces). The somewhat more correct way to do it is `ls "$(which git)"`.

Comment: I have tried with other commands than "ls" and oh it works as expected. It was just an "ls" that doesn't work. Just found "ls" on my setting doesn't point to "/bin/ls" though. It was an alias. Thanks guys, I have just overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using command substitution:

`ls $(which git)`

Comment: Doesn't work though. This outputs the path returned by "which git" but doesn't actually "ls" the path. :(

Comment: @TaoP.R. It works fine for me and others. Note that unless you have an alias for `ls` outputting just a path is what `ls` does. How about `ls -l \`which git\``?

Comment: Oh. My fault. It works for other command than "ls". Your answer is indeed correct. My "ls" has an alias and that's why I can't achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls `which git`
```

Is correct, albeit a little buggy (we'll get to that later). The things within the backticks get replaced with what they print, so the command becomes:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/git
```

There are two *potential* problems, however. Firstly, `which git` *may* print a path that contains spaces (or other scary stuff), so there should be quotes around it. Secondly, backticks are deprecated and discouraged. The preferred syntax is `$()`, which has some advantages (you'll see one in a moment). Thus, the command should be:

```
ls "$(which git)"
```

**Note** This command will just print (since that is what `ls` does):

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

Unless you've set up an alias for `ls` (or have something else called `ls` on your `$PATH` (I shudder at the thought!)).

Since you've expressed some dislike of this result I assume you *either* want some other format, in which case you'll have to add some options to `ls` (either by use of an alias or directly), e.g:

```
ls -lh "$(which git)"
```

*Or* you want to `ls` *the directory* in which `git` resides, in which case you'll have to use `dirname`, like so (here you see that, unlike backticks, `$()` can be nested):

```
ls "$(dirname "$(which git)")"
```

<sup><sup>(Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting doesn't quite understand the quotes within the `$()`. You'll just have to trust me that they're correct.)</sup></sup>

Comment: Just wondering, do we actually need a double quote? Does it make different if we remove that double quote (in theory) so it becomes ls -lh $(which git) instead? Which one is recommended and why?

Comment: You need it for semantic reasons rather than syntactical. If `which git` were to print `/path/with spaces/git` then with and without qoutes would be equivalent to `ls "/path/with spaces/git"` and `ls /path/with spaces/git`, respectively, and the latter will try to `ls` `/path/with` and `spaces/git` as two separate files, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you use back ticks ```

your last example works for me

```
$ ls -al `which git`
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14224 Jun 28  2014 /usr/bin/git
```

the only reason that I could think that it wouldn't is if `which git` returned something with a space.

which should be remedied with the awkward:

```
ls -al "`which git`"
```